# Convert function to LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I have such SQL which select, group and order Url field from Statistic table. `getDomain` is stored function. I am trying to rewrite this SQL to Linq without any luck. Please someone explain how to do that?

```
SELECT  dbo.getDomain(Url) as url
FROM Statistic
GROUP BY dbo.getDomain(Url)
HAVING COUNT(Url) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT(Url)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to [define your UDF in the `.DBML` file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386954.aspx) that contains other tables and procedures definitions. Then you can [Call any UDF function inline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399416.aspx) within your LINQ query Like this:

```
var results = from s in dbo.Statistic
              groub s by dbo.getDomain(s.url) into g
              where g.Count() > 1
              orderby g.Count() ascending
              select new
              {
                  URL = dbo.getDomain(g.Key)
              };
```

Comment: +1 But with LINQ to SQL you do need to set up the function first. You don't get it for free.

Comment: How to alias the 'select dbo.getDomain(g.url)'? I want to give column name. In SQL I write 'Field as url', how to do that in Linq?

Comment: @Tomas you can alias the selected fields into a new anonymous type, see my edit.

Comment: There is something wrong with your code, I get error that the 'g.url' in select clause is not defined.

Comment: @Tomas note that it is case sensitive, so me be it is `g.URL`, check your table definition in the `.DBML` file.

Comment: No, the problem is not in field name, g variable in Select clause do not has any field. Intelisence do not gives any choice.

Comment: I have found where is the problem, g.url should be replaced with g.Key